# Magento 2.3.0 : Adminhtml spreading forms across multiple tabs Doesn't post all fieldset data

Tags: adminhtml, tabs, magento2.3.0

I have created Ui component form with **three tab;**

> **Tab1 and Tab2** are created using 
>    **container and field** but **Tab3** is using  **htmlContent** (with Different form) when i save form

It post only **Tab1's Fieldset Data**.
Question: Why Tab2 data is not post?

Note: same module is working fine on **Magento version  2.2.***

[image]

Comment: can you post your code on creating tabs

Comment: Thank you @magefms  But its solve by changing fieldset name because we have to give fieldset name unique so it might be conflicting name. change name and its done.

Comment: Nice! Enjoy coding bro